# Spring controller adding charset to content type header for image return method

Tags: java, spring, rest, character-encoding, postman

I am writing a simple Spring controller endpoint to return an image from DB, so the image I have is a raw byte array, the code I am using:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getphoto", method = RequestMethod.GET , produces = MediaType.IMAGE_GIF_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> getphoto(@RequestParam(@RequestParam("uuid") UUID uuid) {

    byte[] image = service.getPhoto(uuid);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
    headers.setContentLength(image.length);

    return new ResponseEntity<Resource>(new ByteArrayResource(image), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The problem is that I am getting the image bytes but the content type is always appended with charset like this `image/jpeg;charset=UTF-8` how can I remove that charset for non text mime type? I have tried to add the content type using the strings method `headers.set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");` but still no joy! any suggestions? I believe this charset is preventing lots of testing clients to display the image, like postman in chrome and restclinet in firefox.

**Edit** 
I have managed to remove the charset in many ways, but it looks this is not the only problem in the way I am doing this endpoint, in restclinet I am getting:

> Cannot preview image
>
> Your response is an image, but we need to override the mime type to
>   preview this image. Would you like to override the mime type to
>   "text/xml; charset=x-user-defined" and re-send this request?

when I click yes please continue, the image can be seen in restclient,

[image] in postman in chrome, the image is still not displayed as well.

Comment: Write image byte array to response directly:response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
os.write(image);
os.flush();
os.close();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getphoto", method = RequestMethod.GET , produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> getphoto(@RequestParam(@RequestParam("uuid") UUID uuid) {
    byte[] image = service.getPhoto(uuid);
    ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity = null;
    if(image == null)
        responseEntity = ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    else
        responseEntity = ResponseEntity.ok(image);
    return responseEntity;
}
```

This will put the byte array directly into response as @Henry suggested. And respond with 404 if image[] is null.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that you are you are using the [CharacterEncodingFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.html) with forceEncoding via spring boot, beans or web.xml. That's what I had.